# Error unzipping a file in cmd (using 7z in Windows)

Tags: cmd, 7zip

I am attempting to use 7 Zip through the command line.  As you can see below, using the command `7z l` lists the 3 files in the target zip file.

```
C:\Users\User1\Downloads>7z l recording_20130731180507.zip

--
Path = recording_20130731180507.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 311686

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-07-31 18:05:06 .....          655          655  SD_DISK\20130731\18\2013073
1_180505_A4BC_00408CC2B40B\recording.xml
2013-07-31 18:05:06 .....       309752       309752  SD_DISK\20130731\18\2013073
1_180505_A4BC_00408CC2B40B\20130731_18\20130731_180505_59EB_00408CC2B40B.mkv
2013-07-31 18:05:06 .....          279          279  SD_DISK\20130731\18\2013073
1_180505_A4BC_00408CC2B40B\20130731_18\20130731_180505_59EB_00408CC2B40B.xml
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                310686       310686  3 files, 0 folders
```

However, when I attempt to actually unzip the file, I get a "no files to process error". I've never tried unzipping from cmd before.  Do I have to try to dig into the zip file to extract those 3 files?

```
C:\Users\User1\Downloads>7z e recording_20130731180507.zip o-C:\users\User1\do
cuments\folder1\test


No files to process

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 311686
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The option is `-o`, not `o-`. Run the command like this:

```
7z e recording_20130731180507.zip -o"C:\users\User1\documents\folder1\test"
```

Comment: Note that using `e` will strip out all paths stored in the archive. This may be undesirable.  Consider using `x` instead.